# returning success/failure message to view after database update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to display a status message to a user after they update a profile page to indicate whether it was successful or not. Here is what I have:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profiles(UserProfile model)
{
    try
    {
        _userRepository.UpdateUserProfile(model);
        ViewBag.Message = "Success";
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Failure";
    }
     return View();
}
```

**Database Call**

```
public void UpdateUserProfile(UserProfile user)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLSettings.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("@Id", user.Id);
        p.Add("@City", user.City);
        p.Add("@State", user.State);
        connection.Execute("UpdateUserProfile", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@if (ViewBag.Message == "Success")
{
    <div class="alert alert-success"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Your profile has been updated.</strong></div>
}
@if (ViewBag.Message == "Failure")
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span><strong> Error, please try again.</strong></div>
}
```

While this appears to be working for me, I'm guessing there is a more logical way?

Comment: What do you mean about "more logical way"? Seems nothing wrong from your code here.

Comment: You should really pass a model to your view rather than use ViewBag.

Comment: I guess that I wasn't sure if the `try-catch` should be in the controller or in the actual method making the db call, and returning the success or error from there?

Comment: You could try returning affected row count from the update stored procedure, to help in your assertion.

Comment: try-catch usually made in the DB call method which sends the HTML string into viewmodel to display success or error message after executing query, then bind the viewmodel into the view using `Html.Raw` (also removes if condition in view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider switching to the PRG Pattern in this use case. PRG stands for **POST**-**REDIRECT**-**GET**. In this approach after successfully finishing a transaction (ex :Updating user record), you return a redirect response to the client browser with the new location and browser will make a totally new http get call to load that GET action method.

You can pass TempData to transfer the success message. If there was any error in successfully completing the operation, you may use the `ModelState.AddModelErrorMethod` to add an error to the model state dictionary.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profiles(UserProfile model)
{
    try
    {
        _userRepository.UpdateUserProfile(model);
        TempData["Message"] = "Success";
        return RedirectToAction("Profiles",new { id= model.Id });
    }
    catch
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Some error happened");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Now in your GET action(Profiles?id=someId), you basically need to check the TempData value and display it as needed.

In the case of an error, in the view(`Profiles`), you may use the `Html.ValidationSummary` helper method to show the error message we added to the model state dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation, this was most helpful.