# Display error or success messages into a view after inserting data into a form MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to display error or success messages after populate a form in the view, and if the action method of a controller catch an exception or not then show a message that the registration on a form was successful or not.

This is my HTML code of the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSolictudMarca", "Gestion", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "Frm-login", role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                    {
                        <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:80%;margin:0 auto;">
                            <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="form-group-sm">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <p> <strong>Nº Expediente:</strong></p>
                                                <input class="form-control" id="expedienteNro" name="expedienteNro" type="number" placeholder="Nº Expediente" required autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return pulsarExpediente(event)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br /> 
                                <div class="row ">                                      
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group-sm">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <p><strong>Fecha Solicitud:</strong></p>
                                                @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
                                        .Name("fechaSolicitud")
                                        .Value(DateTime.Now)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", required = "required" })
                                                )
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group-sm">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <p><strong>Fecha Estado:</strong></p>
                                                @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
                                        .Name("fechaEstado")
                                        .Value(DateTime.Now)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", required = "required" })
                                                )
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                                <br /> 
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group-sm">
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <p><strong>Pais:</strong></p>
                                                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                                                  .Name("pais2")
                                                  .DataTextField("PaisDescripcion")
                                                  .DataValueField("PaisCodigo")
                                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", required = "required" })
                                                  .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
                                                  .IgnoreCase(true)
                                                  .Placeholder("Seleccione un país...")
                                                  .DataSource(source =>
                                                  {
                                                      source.Read(read =>
                                                      {
                                                          read.Action("GetPais", "Gestion");
                                                      });
                                                  })
                                                )

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  

                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:30px; width:100%">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    @*@Html.ValidationSummary("error")*@
                                    <div class="alert ">
                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("error", new { @id = "validationMessage" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

And this my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSolictudMarca(FormCollection frm)
    {
        string ExpedienteGeneral =  Request.Form["expedienteNro"];
        string fechaSolicitud = Request.Form["fechaSolicitud"];
        string fechaEstado = Request.Form["fechaEstado"];
        string pais = Request.Form["pais2"];

        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string sqlString = "select * from gmc_expediente where exp_codigo = :selectExpNro";
            string queryRoles = "insert into gmc_expediente(EXP_CODIGO,\n" +
            "EXP_FECHA_SOLICITUD,\n" +
            "EXP_FECHA_ESTADO,\n" +
            "EXP_PAIS)\n" +
            "values(:ExpCodigo,\n" +
            " :fechaSolicitud ,\n" +
            " :fechaEstado,\n" +
            " :pais)";


            #region Conexion 
            string cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDbContext"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(cadena);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(queryRoles, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ExpCodigo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(nuevoExpediente) ? int.Parse(ExpedienteGeneral) : int.Parse(nuevoExpediente)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fechaSolicitud", DateTime.Parse(fechaSolicitud)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fechaEstado", DateTime.Parse(fechaEstado)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pais", int.Parse(pais)));

            #region Procedimiento
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                Permisos.OtorgarPermisos(con);
                using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        //make an insert or update into database
                    }
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //and here when i catch the exception show the message in the view
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();

                }
            }
            #endregion
            return RedirectToAction("RegistroMarca");
        });
    }
```

All i need is if the method action of controller catch an exception show the exact type of exception into a message and display into a view. If it's possible like an alerts message of bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="mostrarAlertSuccess" style="display:none; margin-top:10px">
    <strong>¡Eliminación exitosa!</strong> El registro fue eliminado correctamente.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="mostrarAlertDanger" style="display:none; margin-top:10px">
    <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [returning success/failure message to view after database update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539736/returning-success-failure-message-to-view-after-database-update/40540137#40540137)

Comment: Thanks, i understand now, but can you explain to me this part that you said "Now in your GET action(Profiles?id=someId), you basically need to check the TempData value and display it as needed." How can i display the TempData value into the view?

Answer (score 0):

I Would use `TempData["key"]`

This is like `ViewData["key"]` however the data persists for the next HttpRequest and is disposed automatically by asp.net after this

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomePostAction(SomeViewModel vm)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid) // Is User Input Valid?
   {
       try
       {
           CommitData();
           TempData["UserMessage"] = new { CssClassName = "alert-sucess", Title = "Success!", Message = "Operation Done." };
           return RedirectToAction("Success");
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           TempData["UserMessage"] =  new { CssClassName = "alert-error", Title = "Error!", Message = "Operation Failed." };
           return RedirectToAction("Error");
       }

   }

   return View(vm); // Return View Model with model state errors
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>

     </head>
     <body>
      @if(TempData["UserMessage"] != null)
      {
          <div class="alert @TempData["UserMessage"].CssClassName">
               <strong>@TempData["UserMessage"].Title</strong> @TempData["UserMessage"].Message
          </div>
      }
          @RenderBody()
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i put @TempData["UserMessage"].CssClassName it says 'object' does not contain a definition for  CssClassName.